# Assassin of Kings trophy and the Killing of Radovid

Tags: the-witcher-3

I need help with how to get the Reasons of State side quest, what do I need to do?
Bearing in mind, I am early in the game but I want to know what side quests I need to do, as I hate Radovid and I really want the Assassin of Kings trophy.

Comment: Follow this [walkthru](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/Reason_of_State) and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

it's a side quest that will pop up naturally as you play. you can get it while doing the triss portion of the "final preparation" main quest. I don't know if it effects it, but make sure to do all quests dijkstra gives you when you arrive in novigrad for the first time