# Reason of State quest - did I miss it

Tags: the-witcher-3

so after I beat the game it turned out that this bastard Radovid

> still lived and won the war

even though I had done the quest Deadly plot, so I read a bit and found out that what I need to do it complete the Reason of state quest, that I apparently have to get after getting Phillipa from the bathhouse, so I loaded an earlier save in hopes of amending this mistake

problem is, I never got that quest to begin with, and I am beginning to fear that because instead of being nice I

> broke Dijkstra's leg again :D

I will never be able to access it; is that true, or can i still get it somehow (right now I have done every main quest up to the final battle)?

**tl;dr: what are the exact requirements to get the quest Reason of State quest?**

Comment: you need to complete Triss' sidequest in order to have an interaction with Dijkstra requesting that you help take out dear Rad

Comment: @MatthewPigram But that is the Deadly plot quest tho, where you have to look for a certain guy. Then afterwards I didn't get a follow up either.

Comment: It sounds to me like you have been disqualified from the quest for hurting Dijkstra, from memory the quest is offered once you get Phillipa and in the dialogue you suggest as using her for bait to Dijkstra in order to get him to release her to your custody

Comment: duplicate of : http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/220702/assassin-of-kings-trophy-and-the-killing-of-radovid ?

Comment: Yup, as @MatthewPigram says - that conversation is the direct inspiration for Dijkstra to plan the assassination. Whatever else is needed, that is a must.

Answer (score 2):

The requirements for [*Reasons of State*](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Reason_of_State) are:

1. Complete *A Deadly Plot*
2. Complete *An Eye for an Eye*
3. Complete *Redania's Most Wanted*
4. During *Blindingly Obvious*, do not use force on Dijkstra. Give him information instead.

The quests (1.-3.) will fail automatically if not completed before *The Isle of Mists* (or be unobtainable if not started before that). At point during the game, you see a warning pop up that says:

> Warning! Save your game now!
>
> You are nearing a crucial point in the
> game's story. It is recommended you save your game in a Manual Save
> Slot now.

If you progress past that point, the quests will fail as explained above.

---

Though your question didn't mention *An Eye for an Eye* or *Redania's Most Wanted*, the fact that you broke Dijkstra's leg alone did prevent you from ever getting the quest. So unless you still have a save made before or during *Blindingly Obvious* (or possibly even *The Isle of Mists* if you didn't complete all three prerequisite quests), you unfortunately have to start a new game to get an ending where

> Radovid is dead.